# CSS sprite on small <input type='button'> in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit, chromium

I have an annoying issue in Chromium.

here is the code:

```
<input type="button" class="expand_bt" value=" ">


.expand_bt {
    background: url('../img/actions_btns.jpg') -2340px -542px no-repeat;
    height: 24px;
    width: 26px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

It shows nothing in Chromium, all fine in Firefox. But this:

```
<input class="btn_save" value=" " id="save_general" type="button">

.btn_save {
    background: url('../img/actions_btns.jpg') -178px -550px no-repeat;
    height: 38px;
    width: 122px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

works totally fine in both. Where is the logics? What am I missing?
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Why are you moving the background images so much?

Comment: 1) Because I use CSS sprite 2) It doesn't work for ME o_O

Comment: Get the idea! Chromium didn't load the new version of the sprite! Now I've got somehow to refresh his cache (ctr+shift+r, shift+f5 and ctrl+f5 doesn't help) **UPD** The way is to ctr+shift+r when you load the img in separate window. It's really dumb that it doesn't reload images with developer tools console open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caching issue. I had to go directly to the image location and ctrl+shift+r. Don't know why Chromium didn't refresh the image from cache itself from the containing page.